# How to Set TextInput Field Without Using Value - React Native

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to set the TextInput field without using the value parameter?

I am using _lastNativeText to get data from the field on submission because `onChangeText={}` and `value={}` makes typing lag very badly, so instead I am just getting the input without state via _lastNativeText using a ref like this...

```
<TextInput
  ref={(input) => { myTextInput = input }}
/>
```

Then getting the value with

```
myTextInput._lastNativeText
```

This works fine - it is not my favorite solution, but appears to be the only option I have.

This is for a posts feed. So my question is when I want to edit a post, how do I populate the TextInput using some other native function of which I am not aware?

Using `setText(postData)` and setting `value={text}` is the obvious answer, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
myTextInput.setNativeProps({ text: 'XXXX' })
```